# Get array from separate PHP file and store into jQuery array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I've searched around and wasn't able to find  a clear path for accomplishing this.

I'm familiar with using json_encode() and json_decode() for converting php arrays to and from json, however I'm stumped about the below scenario:

I have a user interactive page where they need to access and use data from one of dozens of php array files. I have a php file (get-array.php) that determines which array to send back based on what the user has been selecting.

Normally I would just use .load() to load php results into a div, but I need the array back and stored in a jQuery array. What would be the best method for doing this?

Many thanks!

Comment: There is no jQuery array. Use `$.ajax()`.

Comment: By the way, there's no 'jQuery array'... As jQuery code is a JavaScript library, and jQuery code is JavaScript, the data structures such as arrays and objects are Javasceipt data structures.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ or the shorthand method, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ to retrieve JSON.

Or even better, this shorthand method is made just for this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

When you have your PHP array a d are ready to send it, you can use the JSON encode method of PHP to prepare it as JSON: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php